# Is there a French equivalent for the typically English "hobbledehoy"?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire, argot

In English, a *hobbledehoy* is a young person who is either clumsy or bad-mannered. (Or presumably both). But this word is both archaic and dialectal. No longer in use (or perhaps only very rarely used) today.

This word was a favourite with Anthony Trollope.

So my question is this: Is there a French equivalent for this English word, which is also dialectal or / and archaic?

Perhaps a good place to find a French equivalent for it is in a French translation of any of Trollope's numerous novels.

Comment: You might find some good words here: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2027544

Comment: @PatrickSebastien You mean _chenapan_, _sacripant_, _galopin_, _galvaudeux_, _garnement_, _maraud_, or _pendard_?

Comment: There seems to be a discussion on which words are better.  I don't have an answer to your question so I am only trying to point you in a good direction, based on what I found during my research.

Comment: the `clumsy` part of the description confuses me. Any the words mentionned by @indoxica don't involve any clumsiness I think, it's almost the contrary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for could be [dadais](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/dadais/).

Then, the bad-mannered part is optional, and should not be seen as Tom Sawyers' bad manners, just that as a matter of fact that young man has bad manners from his clumsiness most probably. This makes a fundamental difference with the words already mentioned in the comments, which all really match some kind of bad intentions from the kid. (say, as much as a kid could have bad intentions)

Comment: _Could_ be, indeed. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

"**grand dadais**" was usual, but didn't mean bad manners, only silliness and clumsiness.

Typically a teenager whose body grew faster than sagacity. That is the reason why it is rarely used without "grand".